# Can one have private macros in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have a case where I have some common functionality within a macro. I have coded that as a macro, but don't want this to be accessible outside the current ftl (just like a private instance variable in Java). One way to do this is to keep the inner macro in a separate file and only include it in this ftl, but that seems to be a bit of a hack. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are no private macros in FreeMarker.

If your only concern is namespace pollution (as opposed to security), you may want to look into `#import`. If you just want to communicate that this macro shouldn't be called from outside, you may start its name with `_`; that means nothing to FreeMarker, but kind of documents that it's something you shouldn't call unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Is there another way in freemarker to get the equivalent of private methods? (Maybe some construct other than macros?)

Comment: Maybe I should understand better why do you need this. One of the confusing things you said is that "one way to do this is to keep the inner macro in a separate file and only include it in this ftl". How does that help?

Comment: I have just started using Freemarker and am trying to get some modularity in my templates. I was trying to apply some object-oriented principles. That is the intent.